# Unexpected text "return"

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement an AuthService from a tutorial of Fireship (https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-firebase-google-oauth-firestore/)

I copied exactly his AuthService:

```
  AuthService() {
    user = Observable(_auth.onAuthStateChanged);

    profile = user.switchMap((FirebaseUser u) => {
      if (u != null) {
        return _db.collection("users").document(u.uid).snapshots().map((snap) => snap.data);
      } else {
        return Observable.just({});
      }
    });
  }
```

I get these errors:

[image]

[image]

If I copy the code from his website (it's exactly the same) there are no errors.
wtf? Can someone explain this or help? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this:

```
    profile = user.switchMap((FirebaseUser u) => {
```

into this:

```
    profile = user.switchMap((FirebaseUser u) {
```

From the [docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions):

> For functions that contain just one expression, you can use a shorthand syntax:
>
> `bool isNoble(int atomicNumber) => _nobleGases[atomicNumber] != null;`
>
> The `=>` expr syntax is a shorthand for { return expr; }. The `=>` notation is sometimes referred to as arrow syntax.

Comment: omg... I was so sure it was the same code .. don't know how I could miss that... THANKS!